# null pointer exception in setting response header in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

```
response.setHeader(keys[i].toString(),value);
```

in a servlet is throwing null pointer exception even though none of keys[i] or value are null why is it so?

Comment: A complete stack trace would be really helpful here.

Comment: @Jim: How is a stacktrace useful in a NPE? Just the actual code of the first line it points to is sufficient. Then you just has to check all the access to a reference if the reference is null or not (there where the dots `.` are been used). You know, you can't invoke methods nor access fields on `null` (this causes the NPE).

Comment: @BalusC A fair cop, I have been reflexively responding this way lately to one-line "why am I getting X exception" questions. @duffymo's answer below is a better way to deal with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the following is true:

1. response is null
2. keys is null
3. keys[i] is null
4. the exception is not thrown from the line you posted.

Comment: About #4, error messages sometimes appear to be from the line after the actual problem; could anything there be null?

Comment: Actually, I think there is one more case: i is of type Integer ('int' wrapper class) and i is null.  I believe the auto-"unboxing" code will result in a NullPointerException.